# Replace Union statement for a less expensive performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this first table:

| word1 | Word 2 | Number 1 | Number 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 | 2 |
| A | B | 1 | 3 |
| A | B | 1 | 4 |
| A | B | 5 | 6 |
| A | B | 5 | 9 |

I would like to transform these 4 columns in 3 columns using all the combinations of column1,column2,number(1+2)

Output:

| word1 | Word 2 | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | B | 3 |
| A | B | 4 |
| A | B | 5 |
| A | B | 6 |
| A | B | 9 |

To achieve this, the following code using "UNION" is working, but if I have really big querys, the time of execution would be multiplyed by 2. So, how could I do it so that it is more efficient that the following solution?

```
SELECT word1, word2, number1 AS number FROM source_table
UNION 
SELECT word1, word2, number2 FROM source_table
```

Comment: Add LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL into one of the subqueries and apply UNION ALL. You'll eliminate one sorting step. Of course according indices must exist.

Comment: @Akina please, could you write it in code, I am not understanding you. Thanks

Comment: It may be more like 3x -- copy to tables to temp table, sort & de-dup, then deliver the results.  But it may be optimal.

Comment: Is `number2` always `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    SELECT word1, word2, number1 AS number 
    FROM source_table
UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.word1, t1.word2, t1.number2 
    FROM source_table t1
    LEFT JOIN source_table t2 
        ON (t1.word1, t1.word2, t1.number2) = (t2.word1, t2.word2, t2.number1)
    WHERE t2.number1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Depending on the version being used, that use of "row constructors" may fail to be optimized.  The desired index would be the composite `INDEX(word1, word2, number1)`.  Let us know if this is any faster.

Comment: @RickJames In MySQL the condition which uses row constructor is not a problem, because parsing it to separate conditions is one of the steps of the execution plan building and optimizing. And when according index exists, it is used even when the columns order in the row constructor and in the condition does not match. And you're right, the indices by `(word1, word2, number1)` and by `(word1, word2, number2)` will improve.

Comment: Yes, MySQL has 'always' handled row constructors _correctly_.  But, only recently does the Optimizer understand how to use an `INDEX` for tests like that.  The way the query is written, I think only `(word1, word2, number1)` is needed.

Comment: Oh...  I don't think your answer works -- Notice that [A,B,1] shows up 3 times in the input, but only once in the output.